# Microsoft Threat modeling tool element properties document or resource

Tags: security, sdl, wcf-security

I started using the Microsoft Threat Modeling tool. Is there a document or resource that explains in detail what each element and element properties mean and purpose?

Answer (score -1):

In Microsoft Threat modeling tool

**Element properties**

Element properties vary by the elements you select. Apart from trust boundaries, all other elements contain three general selections:

**Name**: Useful for naming your processes, stores, interactors, and flows so that they're easily recognized.

**Out of scope**: If selected, the element is taken out of the threat-generation matrix (not recommended).

**Reason for out of scope**: Justification field to let users know why out of scope was selected.

Properties are changed under each element category. Select each element to inspect the available options.

For more details you can check out this document, which comes with a PDF eBook.

[Threat Modeling Tool feature overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security/develop/threat-modeling-tool-feature-overview)